# Variables and Storage in ionic 3 Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular2-forms

First of all I have

```
<timer #timer [timeInSeconds]="this.store" timerFont></timer></p>
```

I want the value of Timer to be grabbed from the function `getBalance()`

```
getBalance(){
    this.restProvider.getBalance(this.user_id)
        .then(data => {
            this.todos = data;
            this.balance = this.todos.balance;
            this.timersecs = this.todos.timer;
            /// HERE ///
        });  
}
```

The problem is `this.balance` value is stored within the function of `RestProvider` but if I want to call `this.balance` from `Constructor` or other function I won't be able to do so. How can I reference the value from functions outside of the `RestProvider` `getBalance()` function?

Comment: can you please elaborate you query more?

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose your getBalance function is in a page component called MyPage. Then you can do this:

```
export class MyPage {

balance: number;

getBalance(outerThis: MyPage){
    this.restProvider.getBalance(this.user_id)
        .then(data => {
            this.todos = data;
            outerThis.balance = this.todos.balance;
            this.timersecs = this.todos.timer;
            /// HERE ///
        });  
}
```

then depending on where you are calling getBalance() from, you would pass a reference to your page as a parameter. E.g. if calling from somewhere within the page itself, you would say:

```
this.getBalance(this);
```